# Previously working spark jobs only now throwing "java.io.IOException: Too many open files" error?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdp

Running a HortonWork hadoop cluster (HDP-3.1.0.0) and getting a bunch of

> Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Too many open files

errors when running spark jobs that *up until this point have worked fine*.

I have seen many other questions like this where the answer is to increase the ulimit settings for open files and processes (this is also in [the HDP docs](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/security-reference/content/kerberos_nonambari_limits_conf.html)) (and I'll note that I believe that mine are still at the system default settings), but...

My question is: **Why is this only happening now** when previously the spark jobs have been running fine for months?

The spark jobs I have been running have been running fine for months without incident and I have made no recent code changes. Don't know enough about the internals of spark to theorize about why things could be going wrong only now (would be odd to me if open files just build up in the course of running spark, but that seems like what is happening).

Just as an example, just this code...

```py
.
.
.
sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("GET_TABLE_COUNT").getOrCreate()
sparkSession._jsc.sc().getExecutorMemoryStatus().keySet().size()
.
.
.
```

now generates errors like...

```sh
.
.
.
[2020-05-12 19:04:45,810] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 20/05/12 19:04:45 INFO Client: Application report for application_1579648183118_19918 (state: ACCEPTED)
[2020-05-12 19:04:46,813] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 20/05/12 19:04:46 INFO Client: Application report for application_1579648183118_19918 (state: ACCEPTED)
[2020-05-12 19:04:47,816] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 20/05/12 19:04:47 INFO Client: Application report for application_1579648183118_19918 (state: ACCEPTED)
[2020-05-12 19:04:48,818] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 20/05/12 19:04:48 INFO Client: Application report for application_1579648183118_19918 (state: ACCEPTED)
[2020-05-12 19:04:49,820] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 20/05/12 19:04:49 INFO Client: Application report for application_1579648183118_19918 (state: ACCEPTED)
[2020-05-12 19:04:50,822] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 20/05/12 19:04:50 INFO Client: Application report for application_1579648183118_19918 (state: ACCEPTED)
[2020-05-12 19:04:51,828] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 20/05/12 19:04:51 INFO Client: Application report for application_1579648183118_19918 (state: FAILED)
[2020-05-12 19:04:51,829] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 20/05/12 19:04:51 INFO Client:
[2020-05-12 19:04:51,829] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -      client token: N/A
[2020-05-12 19:04:51,829] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -      diagnostics: Application application_1579648183118_19918 failed 2 times due to Error launching appattempt_1579648183118_19918_000002. Got exception: java.io.IOException: DestHost:destPort hw005.co.local:45454 , LocalHost:localPort hw001.co.local/172.18.4.46:0. Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
[2020-05-12 19:04:51,829] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor808.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[2020-05-12 19:04:51,829] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

This code is being run with...

```sh
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python;                 
/bin/spark-submit \
    --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC" \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC" \
    --conf "spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1" \
    --jars /home/airflow/tmp/ojdbc6.jar \
    /path/to/my/script.py
```

My RAM and `ulimit` setting on the cluster look like...

```sh
[root@HW001]# clush -ab free -h
---------------
HW001
---------------
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        9.0G        1.1G        1.7G         21G         19G
Swap:          8.5G         44K        8.5G
---------------
HW002
---------------
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        7.3G        5.6G        568M         18G         22G
Swap:          8.5G        308K        8.5G
---------------
HW003
---------------
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        6.1G        4.0G        120M         21G         24G
Swap:          8.5G        200K        8.5G
---------------
HW004
---------------
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        2.9G        2.8G        120M         25G         27G
Swap:          8.5G         28K        8.5G
---------------
HW005
---------------
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        2.9G        4.6G        120M         23G         27G
Swap:          8.5G         20K        8.5G
---------------
airflowetl
---------------
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            46G        5.3G         13G        2.4G         28G         38G
Swap:          8.5G        124K        8.5G
[root@HW001]#
[root@HW001]#
[root@HW001]#
[root@HW001]# clush -ab ulimit -a
---------------
HW[001-005] (5)
---------------
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 127886
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 127886
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
---------------
airflowetl
---------------
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 192394
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 192394
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Don't know much about Hadoop admin, but just looking at the Ambari dashboard, the cluster does not seem to be overly taxed...
[image]
(though could not actually check the RM web UI, since it just throws a "too many open files" error).

Anyone with more spark/hadoop experience know why this would be happening now?

Comment: Note that the Linux "limits" are set _per user_ and that `root` usually has higher limits than other users. Ambari should set specific limits for Hadoop accounts such as `yarn`. I advise to (a) look at the Linux settings in `limits.conf` and `limits.d/*` (b) focus on the actual user that runs the Spark job _and_ on the `yarn` user (c) try increasing the settings before restarting the YARN services

Comment: On the other hand, maybe your RM and/or NM processes are leaking file descriptors and simply need a restart to hide the problem under the carpet. These things are not very stable.